# Making DBContext calls from AutoMapper MapFrom Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, automapper

I'm using AutoMapper and EF on my current MVC project.

In some of my CreateMap calls, I am mapping some of the properties using a call to EF, as follows:

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<Geography, DropdownListViewModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Items,
                opts => opts.MapFrom(src => profileService.GetGeographies()));
```

In this example, my profileService.GetGeographies method is making a call to EF to retrieve the geographies.  My question is regarding the lifetime management of the profileService (and its underlying dbContext instance).  Is AutoMapper going to keep the reference to profileService alive throughout the life of the app?  If so, my chief concern is that the underlying dbContext will get stale (I'm using per-request DI of the DbContext into the ProfileService class.

Would it be a better approach to use a custom ValueResolver class that wraps the ProfileService since I'm assuming these are instantiated each time a mapping occurs?  In that scenario, I can make a service locator call to the IoC container to retrieve a dbContext instance, which should give me a per-request instance?

**UPDATE**

Upon further review, I realized that I can simply do the following:

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<Geography, DropdownListViewModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Items,
                opts => opts.MapFrom(src => DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IProfileService>().GetGeographies()));
```

This should allow AutoMapper to use a fresh IProfileService each time a mapping occurs.

Comment: I think that is similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826013/automapper-custom-resolver-inject-repository-into-constructor

Comment: It's definitely not a good idea to call out to a database in the `MapFrom` call. A custom `ValueResolver` may be better, but I have a feeling even that may not actually be necessary. Can you post the contents of both `Geography` and `DropdownListViewModel`. Maybe with that someone can suggest a more foolproof solution.

Comment: Ultimately, many of these service methods will likely cache their data after the first DB call since much of this data will rarely change.  However, there will likely be a few cases in which I'll need to connect to a fresh dbContext each time in order to do the mapping.  I think the update I posted above should do the trick.

Comment: What is the benefit of using AutoMapper here over a `ToDropdownListViewModel()` method on the `Geography` class or a `FromGeography` method on the `DropdownListViewModel`? Are there many fields that the two classes have in common?